# htaccess redirect from one domain to another domains subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, .htaccess

I want to redirect this way: from www.example.com/link.php?a=1&b=1 to www.example.net/subdirectory/link.php?a=1&b=1

I tried to use this .htaccess which isn't working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/subdirectory$ [L,R=301]
```

The above redirects www.example.com/link.php?a=1&b=1 to www.example.net/subdirectory/?a=1&b=1, omitting the link.php part.

System is apache2.2 + mod_rewrite running on debian wheezy 64bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put `$` at the end of the RewriteRule, but you'll want the first capture group of your regex (the `.*` bit of `^(.*)$`). That is fetched with `$1`, also mind you'll still need a trailing slash at the end. So, all in all, update your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/subdirectory/$1 [L,R=301]
```

`http://www.example.com/link.php?a=1&b=1` would then be rewritten to `http://www.example.net/subdirectory/link.php?a=1&b=1`